# DOOM emacs Move Cider REPL windows vertical

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I'd like to ask how to move cider repl in DOOM, from horizontal (screenshot below) to vertical? been trying many menus shortcut but still horizontal.

Thanks you so much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAQu0.png)

Comment: Yo, look at the preview before you post. The image isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned, in DOOM this REPL window is [transformed into a popup](https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/blob/c7753adbb301dcb647dc96d182c28b228551890e/modules/lang/clojure/config.el#L53), and you can customize it in your `.doom.d/config.el`:

```
(after! cider
  (set-popup-rules!
   '(("^\\*cider-repl"
      :side right
      :width 100
      :quit nil
      :ttl nil))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to achieve this is by splitting the windows vertically before jacking into Cider. I.e., in your source code file, hit `C-x 3` which calls `split-window-right`.

Of course, you could write a small Elisp function to call this before jacking into Cider (you might want a `defadvice`), but you would have to check your current window layout first, so I never bothered to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Doom uses a pop-up for the REPL window, so the simplest way would be to disable popups. Otherwise, you can maximize the popup (Ctrl ~), and split the window vertically...